# start osgi bundle from main class rather than implementing BundleActivator

Tags: java, bundle, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I hava a jar file named floodlight.jar. I can run it in cmd line: java -jar floodlight.jar. Now I want to convert it into a bundle to deploy with FUSE ESB container. Here is what I did so far:

1. convert:

   ```
    java -jar bnd.jar wrap floodlight.jar
   ```

   result in a bundle named floodlight.bar. change the name to floodlight.jar
2. deploy

   ```
   FuseESB:karaf@root> osgi:install -s file:/home/usr/Dir/to/floodlight.jar
   ```

I hope the bundle can do the same thing as what i did in cmd line: java -jar floodlight.jar once it getting started. However, it is active without doing anything. It just behaves like a library.

I am wondering how to let the bundle run the main class once it is started. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid writing a `Bundle-Activator`? If it's about duplication of code then you can just call `main()` from your activator's `start()` method.

Comment: Because there are some java applications, like floodlight, oracle noslqlDB, ready to run. I just want to deploy these applications to OSGi container without many changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry point for OSGi applications are BundleActivator's. You can not invoke the main-method like in standard Java applications. However, you can do all the stuff you would do in the main method in the start(BundleContext) method of your bundle.

So, implement the BundleActivator interface and add it to your manifest.

Comment: Is it just like coping the content from main class to BundleActivator.start()? Then add the Activator to manifest?

Comment: You might have to change a little bit, depending on your programm. But in general, yes, start() is OSGi's main()! But keep in mind that converting a 'standard' programm to a modular osgi application may cause some issues due to OSGi's extended class loading